# Can substitution be used to solve a single equation that represent a partial order with two variables?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory, substitution

I am still trying to wrap my head around partial orders and my algebra is not the best...
My question is pertains to the following example:

ex.) Let a relation R be defined on the set of real numbers as follows:
$ xRy ⇔ 2x +y = 3 $
Prove that this relation is antisymmetric.

Solution: aRb is $(2a+b=3)$, since bRa  is $2b+a=3$ 
$(2a+b)−(2b+a) = 3−3 $ 
$2a + b − 2b − a = 0$ 
$a−b=0 $ 
$a = b $

My question is, why subtract the two equations? Do we subtract the two equations because a partial order is a way to quantify how objects in a set are different from each other?And is it possible to solve the same equation by substitution?

I solved:
$2x + y = 3 $ 
$x= 3-y/2 $

and plugged x back into the equation and solved for y.
$2(3-y/2)+y=3 $ 
$3-y+y=3$ 
$3+y=3+y $  
$y=y$

I tested a few values to find that the equation 2x+y=3 is true for any value y that is added to 2(3-y/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show antisymmetry we have to show that given $xRy$ and $yRx$ the equality $x=y$ follows. Here we have the situation that since $xRy$ is defined as $2x+y=3$ the system of equations
\begin{align*}
2x+y&=3\tag{1}\\
x+2y&=3\tag{2}
\end{align*}
is valid.

> We can do any admissible equivalence transformations with (1) and (2) to find out if $x=y$ is true. This means that we can subtract (1) from (2) to come to a conclusion as well as applying the substitution method. So, both  approaches are fine.

*Hint:* Your calculation needs to be revised somewhat. In fact from $2x+y=3$ it follows $x=\frac{3-y}{2}$. Substitution of $x=\frac{3-y}{2}$ in $x+2y=3$ results in $y=1$ and we finally get $\color{blue}{x=y}=1$.

Comment: Thank you, epi163dqrt - that is really cool.

Comment: @Lizzo: You're welcome! :-)